# insert values into a table from column names of 2 or different tables?

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Please help me in resolving this query.

1. Table t1 having "t1c1" and "t1c2" columns.
2. Table t2 having "t2c2" and "t2c2" columns.

I have to insert values into t3 table having "t3c1","t3c2",t3c3" columns.

The condition is that "t3c2" column values should be populated from "t1c2" column and "t3c3" column should be populated from "t2c2" column and "t3c1" should be populated from cursor values.

Can someone help in this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
INSERT INTO t3 (t3c1, t3c2, t3c3)
SELECT currval, t1.t1c2, t2.t2c2
FROM t1, t2;
```

If you need to match only certain rows in `t1` and `t2`, you can add:

```
WHERE t1.t1c1 = 'value'
  AND t2.t2c1 = 'value';
```

Comment: hi benjamin... all is correct except for the t3c1 column which should be a cursor value... how do i insert into that column using a cursor value

Comment: @kattashri Sorry, I'm not competent with Oracle, I cannot help you more than that!

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t3(t3c1,t3c2,t3c3) 
    (select curval,t1.t1c2,t2.t2c2 from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.col=t2.col)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if i understand your question.
May be some code in SQL would be better than other desctiption. If i undestand you have this view

```sql
CREATE VIEW t3 as SELECT t1c2 AS t3c2, t2c2 AS t3c3, rowid (oid ... or something) AS t3c1 FROM t1,t2 WHERE ....
```

Then you can make a triger `INSTEAD OF`

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER t3_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON t3 AS BEGIN
  INSERT t1 .... VALUES (NEW.t3c1 .....)
  .......   
END;
```

or if t3 is regular table and you want to modify your data in t3 then use trigger `AFTER INSERT (UPDATE,DELETE)`

Be more specific, you can will receive a better solution.

Comment: ya t3 is a regular table and am not trying to modify the t3 table but am trying to populate t3 table where its columns is the values from another table and one of its columns is a cursor value